# Syntax for data binding with Index

Tags: vue.js

Stuck on what is most likely just a syntax issue.  I want to replace the '1' in 'play1' with the v-for index.

```
<tr v-for="index in 5">
  <td>{{player1.round1.play1}}</td>
  <td>{{player2.round1.play1}}</td>
</tr>
```

I tried many variations of {{player1.round1.play + index}} with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr v-for="index in 5">
  <td>{{player1.round1['play'+index]}}</td>
  <td>{{player2.round1['play'+index]}}</td>
</tr>
```

within the double-curlies of the vue template, the content is handled as javascript.

when looking up an object in javascript you can either pass the key using the `dot notation` or the `bracket syntax`.

For example, if you have an object such as this:

```
const objectA = {
  objectB: {
    objectC: {
    }
  }
};
```

you can look up objectC either using dot notation:
`objectA.objectB.objectC`

or using brackets:
`objectA['objectB']['objectC']`

note that when you are using brackets, that you **have** to use a simple type, a number or a string (technically symbols are also accepted, but let's not worry about that right now). The bracket syntax *does* however allow you to use a variable in order to access an object, like so:

```
let b='objectB';
let c='C';
objectA[b]['object' + c];
objectA[b][`object${c}`];
```

knowing this, you can then use that to access the right object inside your vue template like this:

```
<td>{{player1.round1['play'+index]}}</td>
```

or, using *template literals*:

```
<td>{{player2.round1[`play${index}`]}}</td>
```

Comment: While this will probably solve the problem, can you explain WHY it works the way it does? Also, the backtick strings aren't really necessary here :/

Comment: correct, I removed the template literals, but added example using them properly